# How to installing JBoss server in CentOs?

Tags: jboss

I am installing JBoss in my pc. It is CentOs operating system

While installing it is showing

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify your Java home path  is set by using

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If it java path is not in environment 
install and initialize

```
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_12/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_12
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```